# Setting SElinux Labels for a magento site on Centos 7

Tags: centos, security, centos7, selinux, content-security-policy

I was hoping someone could kindly help myself. I have a Magento site running on a Centos 7.6 server.

Now, the site is not correctly loading and looking in the messages.log I see numerous entries where SElinux is blocking access. I am able to confirm it is a SElinux issue as setting in permissive mode fixes ("used loosely") the problem.

> Running `sealert -l 3bedf708-7636-44d4-95f6-c98b8ea16687`, I see the following:
>
> SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from write access on
>   /var/www/html/MyMagentoSite/var/session/

There is various entries for different files and folders.

Would I be okay in just running `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/magentofoldername/*`, or what would be a better solution?

This seems counter intuitive, in that I am giving read and write to all within the magento folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why not follow your intuition and apply the label to only the `session` directory (from your error message).

Still, intuition is not the best helper here but you can do some lookups on what are the "expected" labels, using detective skills.

Default PHP session directory is `/var/lib/php/session`.

If you do a `semanage fcontext -l | grep php` then you can see this entry:

```
/var/lib/php(/.*)? all files system_u:object_r:httpd_var_lib_t:s0
```

So the PHP session directory should, I suppose, be labeled as `httpd_var_lib_t`.

So:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_var_lib_t /var/www/html/magentofoldername/var/session
```

Comment: The session folder is the magento folder within {magento_root/var} I am thinking httpd_sys_rw_content_t is a better label

Comment: It stores *PHP sessions* nonetheless :)

Comment: Parson the stupidity, would this label allow httpd process to write?

Comment: Looking at the man page `Set files with the httpd_var_lib_t type, if you want to store the httpd files under the /var/lib directory.`The files within said folder are not stored in this directory

Answer (score 0):

If you use `chcon` and after you reboot the server, you will have the same issue, use `semanage fcontext` in this way:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_var_lib_t "/var/www/html/magentofoldername/var/session(/.*)?"
```

Now you can apply the selinux permissions:

```
restorecon -R -v -F   /var/www/html/magentofoldername/var/session
```

Comment: Files aren't under `/var/ib`, thus won't httpd_var_lib_t be the wrong label? I am thinking httpd_sys_rw_content_t

Comment: check using semanage fcontext -l and check see what kind label php session files has

Comment: Hey is there a way to recursively set for subfolder using semenage fcontext?